# Create button that deletes items from local storage one by one

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

for a project I need to create a program that from input adds info to separate page, I need to create a button that would delete local storage entry one by one.

My index.html

```
<body>

    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="addItem.html">Create a new task</a>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <div id="showData"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my HTML to which items are placed

```
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="addItem.html">Create a new task</a>

    <h1>Create a Task</h1>
    
    <form id="myForm" action="/data.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Item">
        <button  id="delete-button" value="Delete"></button>
        
    </form>


</body>
```

My JS:

```
let myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
if (myForm != null) {
    myForm.addEventListener("submit", AddItem);

}

item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myItem")) || [];

function AddItem(event) {
    event.preventDefault ();
    let getUser = document.getElementById("user").value;
    myObj = {
        user: getUser 
    }
    item.push(myObj);
    localStorage.setItem("myItem", JSON.stringify(item));
}

let getDataDiv = document.getElementById("showData");
item.forEach(element => {
    if (getDataDiv != null) {
    let h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    h3.textContent += element.user;
    getDataDiv.append(h3);
    }
}); 

function removeItem() {
    let deleteButton = document.getElementById('delete-button');
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('h3');
        });
}
```

I have tried to add button that would delete it one entry at the time using addEventListener and remove item.

Comment: Not very clear, why are you setting `"myItem"` to localStorage, but deleting `"h3"` item?

Comment: I have tried to change to removeItem('myItem'); but it still does nothing.

Comment: Did you call `removeItem` function somewhere?

Comment: I called removeItem with button id="delete-button" , but it does not delete entries.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to use array/list and use FIFO (first-in first-out) to delete the value one by one then update the list to localstorage.

something like...

```
let arr = []
function submitted() {
    // when click submit
    arr.push(value);
    //then update the local storage
    localStorage.setItem("arr", arr);
}

//when remove btn is clicked
function remove() {
      arr.splice(-1);
      //then update the local storage
      localStorage.setItem("arr", arr);
}
```

can check this to see the logic [here](https://carlsaqui29.github.io/wiballstore.github.io/)
this is the repo [here](https://github.com/CarlSaqui29/wiballstore.github.io)